# Deduplicate the data using ROW_NUMBER in Snowflake when all the columns have the same data

Tags: sql, duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

| project_id | calendar_date | has_sow | sow_activity_status | sow_review_activity_actual_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 2024-03-01 | null | Not Completed | null |
| P1 | 2024-03-01 | null | Not Completed | null |
| P1 | 2024-03-01 | null | Not Completed | null |
| P1 | 2024-03-01 | null | Not Completed | null |
| P1 | 2024-04-01 | null | Not Completed | null |
| P1 | 2024-04-01 | null | Not Completed | null |
| P1 | 2024-04-01 | null | Not Completed | null |
| P1 | 2024-04-01 | null | Not Completed | null |
| P2 | 2024-03-01 | null | Completed | 2023-12-20 |
| P2 | 2024-03-01 | null | Completed | 2023-12-20 |
| P2 | 2024-03-01 | null | Completed | 2023-12-20 |
| P2 | 2024-03-01 | null | Completed | 2023-12-20 |
| P2 | 2024-04-01 | null | Completed | 2023-12-20 |
| P2 | 2024-04-01 | null | Completed | 2023-12-20 |
| P2 | 2024-04-01 | null | Completed | 2023-12-20 |
| P2 | 2024-04-01 | null | Completed | 2023-12-20 |

The above table is the source data, the final expected output is :

| project_id | calendar_date | has_sow | sow_activity_status | sow_review_activity_actual_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 2024-03-01 | null | Not Completed | null |
| P1 | 2024-04-01 | null | Not Completed | null |
| P2 | 2024-03-01 | null | Completed | 2023-12-20 |
| P2 | 2024-04-01 | null | Completed | 2023-12-20 |

The expected output can be achieved using distinct query, i.e.

```
select 
    distinct project_id, calendar_date, has_sow, sow_activity_status, sow_review_activity_actual_date
from source ;
```

Would like to achieve the same using ROW_NUMBER since the data is around a Million records.
So will be partitioning the ROW_NUMBER window function by project_id, calendar_date but don't know on which column it should be ordered by because all the remaining columns will have the same data at the grain of the project_id and calendar_date ?

Need advice in figuring out the order by clause for ROW_NUMBER function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DISTINCT` here seems like the right approach to me.  I don't recommend using `ROW_NUMBER` to remove your duplicates.  As an alternative, you could use `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT project_id, calendar_date, has_sow, sow_activity_status, sow_review_activity_actual_date
FROM source
GROUP BY project_id, calendar_date, has_sow, sow_activity_status, sow_review_activity_actual_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by `ROW_NUMBER` with `ORDER BY` any column (take `project_id`) as follows:

```
select <all_Columns> from
(select t.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by <all_columns> order by project_id) as rn
  from your_table t) t
where rn = 1;
```

`row_number` will always gives the unique row number to the partitioned records even if `order by` columns have same values.

Answer (score 1):

if the order is not important, you can use

```
select *
from source
qualify row_number()over(partition by project_id, calendar_date order by 1)=1
```

you can also just do "group by project_id, calendar_date" if you don't care about the other records...